# How to send image/pdffile from android to android with database

Tags: android, base64, instant-messaging

I want to try developing an android application that can send image/pdfFile from android to android device. For example i have a list of patients. when i click an item it will go to send file to patient that i have clicked. Then the sent file will be stored in database. and will serve as sent file history. Just like an instant messaging. I found an example of instant messaging but this only sending texts not images/files

here [AndroidIM](https://github.com/Pirngruber/AndroidIM)

Could anyone convert it to sending images?I really don't know how. Or just link me to some tutorial in sending images/files to another device. I am using also database for storing history of sent files.

Comment: do you have a backend ?

Comment: yes. I am using Xampp  localhost database @Amrola

Comment: how you connect to the database ?

Comment: i use PHP this PHP serve as a bridge between android and mysql database

Comment: great , so what you have to do is send the image to the other user using the php and insert it in the database .
and then notify the other user that he got some new messages in the database

Comment: good if text only. i don't know how to send image. A code for java

Comment: please post and update your question how you send text ? and i then i will post how to upload images .

Comment: @Amrola i already posted how to send text and its already posted. check the link

Comment: i will not go through the whole project to find how you send an HTTP request , please post the part related here .
so we could help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

send the image to you PHP backend using the Http MultiPart Request like the following :

```
try{
 HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);

    MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(
            HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

    File file = new File(imagePath);
    ContentBody encFile = new FileBody(file,"image/png");

    entity.addPart("images", encFile);
    request.setEntity(entity);

}catch(Exception e ){

}
```

and please give me some feedback .

Hope That Helps .

Comment: @user3226149 can you tell me how you solved problem. I am developing some apps that require pdfs and image sending.